# React Redux: Use data from props or get data directly from redux-store? Which one is better?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Please excuse if its a duplicate.

I was just going through some nice `Open source React+Redux projects` and I came through this [`Ory-editor`](https://github.com/ory/editor) in which they have tried to get the data from store directly in almost every component.

Example -

```
const Inner = ({
  isInsertMode,
  insertMode
}: {
  isInsertMode: boolean,
  insertMode: Function
}) => (
  <Button
    icon={<ContentAdd />}
    description="Add things"
    active={isInsertMode}
    onClick={insertMode}
  />
)

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({ isInsertMode })
const mapDispatchToProps = { insertMode }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Inner)
```

> So this made me wonder if its a good practice to get data directly from redux-store for all components or is it better to pass the data using React props.

Which way is better and faster? And doesn't hurt React's basic principles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are passing the data through `props` you will still need at one point to take it out from the `redux-store`.

If you are passing data from another component, you will mix that component *concern* and you will find yourself passing data through 3-4-5 layers even though you use it only in one.

The beauty of the `redux-store` is that you can access the `store` everywhere, therefore *decoupling* components.

Comment: I see. That means get the data directly from store as far as you can!!

Answer (score 2):

In React there is a pattern of 'Smart' and 'Dumb' components, often referred as Container and Presentational components.

I found this a very helpful article https://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/ where it says:

> **Smart Component Characteristics**
>
> - Describe how things work
> - Provide no DOM markup or styles
> - Provide application data, do data fetching
> - Call Flux actions
> - Named *Container by convention
>
> **Dumb Component Characteristics**
>
> - Describe how things look
> - Have no app dependencies
> - Receive only props, providing data and callbacks
> - Rarely have own state, when they do, it’s just UI state
> - Named anything that’s a UI noun

Hope I could help!

Comment: One of the original container/presentational component articles (written by the developer of Redux) is also worth a read: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is always write dumb component first for example ComponentBase, than use connect and create smart if you need it. This is good if you need reuse component you can pass props directly or you can write new one with connect and for example connect ComponentBase to different stores.

This approach is good also for testing or for example if you are using Storybook.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on connecting multiple components](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components):

> Early Redux documentation advised that you should only have a few connected components near the top of your component tree. However, time and experience has shown that that generally requires a few components to know too much about the data requirements of all their descendants, and forces them to pass down a confusing number of props.
>
> The current suggested best practice is to categorize your components as “presentational” or “container” components, and extract a connected container component wherever it makes sense:
>
> > Emphasizing “one container component at the top” in Redux examples was a mistake. Don't take this as a maxim. Try to keep your presentation components separate. Create container components by connecting them when it's convenient. Whenever you feel like you're duplicating code in parent components to provide data for same kinds of children, time to extract a container. Generally as soon as you feel a parent knows too much about “personal” data or actions of its children, time to extract a container.
>
> In fact, benchmarks have shown that more connected components generally leads to better performance than fewer connected components.